# How can I substract random no from 100 to 0 by another random no 1-10 and print subtraction no in c#?

Tags: c#, random

so basically I have 100-0 no and 1-10 no. now i have to go from 100 to 0 by substracting random no by 1-10 and print those subtraction no.
I have used for loop to solve this problem. but this problem have to solve without decrement just randomly. here is my code.

```
for(int i = 100; i >=0; i--) {
            Random ran = new Random();
            int randomNum = ran.Next(1, 10);
            int val = i - randomNum;
            if (val >= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val);
                i--;
            }
        }
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: `but this problem have to solve without decrement just randomly` <- WHAT?

Comment: In the title of the question you're saying about random value from 0 to 100, but in the code you're going through every number in the range [0, 100]. So I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve. Could you please try to come up with example of the result?

Comment: Do not create a new instance of Random inside the loop, move that to just before the loop

Comment: Try stepping through the code in the debugger, observing what the values of the various variables are. Or (temporarily) replace the `ran.Next(..)` with `5` and observe what really happens - is that what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this line:

> i--;

For loop already does that after every loop.

*Sorry i can't add command.*